# Adding a product search bar that searches by number and brings back price from TXT file

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to update my Wordpress / Wooocommerce store with an additional search bar where you could enter a specific part number needed.

I have a TXT file with around 50000 products. There are 2 columns separated by ",". Each line is 1 product. First column has the part numbers and the second has the price.

I would like the search bar to return the price of the product (specific number) by looking at the TXT file that has all the numbers and prices.
And for the client to be able to add it to cart.

Can anybody guide my trough it? Have not been able to find such a plugin.
Thanks, Carl.

Comment: This sounds like a `.csv` (comma separated value)  file. It might be good to do a search on how to import or a plugin that uses such a structure.

Comment: As I see it, you have to write your own PHP or JS code, which reads the file and does the search.